# php include path issue

Tags: php, path, include

Although this has been asked a thousand times I still managed to screw things up and not find an answer that serves my issue..

I have 2 files

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\MF\Pages\ads.php
C:\xampp\htdocs\MF\Pages\ads_view.php
```

I wanna include `ads_view` from `ads` what I do is

```
echo __DIR__;
var_dump(file_exists('ads_view.php'));
```

and what I get is

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\MF\Pages
bool(false)
```

Why can't I include this file when `__DIR__` clearly states i'm in the parent folder? `ads.php` is also included from another file, if that makes any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please put the full path it should work

```
var_dump(file_exists('C:\xampp\htdocs\MF\Pages\ads_view.php'));
```

see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) for file_exists

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` variable in $_SERVER for portability.

`var_dump(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '\MF\Pages\ads_view.php'));`

and

`include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '\MF\Pages\ads_view.php';`

Comment: It's actually weird because `include` works just well with relative paths but `file_exists` doesn't >.<

Comment: Thats because, like meda said, fil_exists expects a complete path to a file while include also works with current directory and relative paths (like ../../ etc.). But i like to use document_root so i can copy the code to other files in other directories without changing the path. A "c:\path..." etc. would work too but if i copy the code to another site it would stop working.

Comment: you can simply use `__DIR__` instead of document root

Comment: @php_nub_qq: You are right for just file_exists. Then its simpler to use `__DIR__`. But for an include, **especially** outside your own directory i would still use document_root and not a hard-coded path.